# How do i change the pivot point of the "Rotate" text fields in the Transform panel?

Tags: animation, transforms

I've already figured out how to set a pivot point for the normal Rotate tool in the Toolbar, but whenever i try to animate something rotating, it always ends up rotating around the axis (in this case the Y axis) instead of rotating around the pivot point that i previously set it to. Keyframes seem to look at the "Rotate" text fields in the Properties panel instead of how i actually rotate it using the Rotate tool in the Toolbar, which is why the title is phrased like that.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate an object around an origin other than the object's origin, it changes both the object's rotation and location.  As a result, when you set your keyframes, you'll want to use "LocRot" rather than "Rotation."